# unset variable in mongo shell

Tags: shell, mongodb, variables

Is there a way to unset a variable in the mongo shell. For example if I try to reference `myvar` before defining it, I get `ReferenceError: myvar is not defined (shell):1`, but once I define it and I'm finished with it, I'd like to return it to that state.

I tried setting it to `null` and `undefined`, neither of which worked.

EDIT: When trying the delete operator, I get the following output:

```
> var myvar = 5
> myvar
5
> delete myvar
false
> 
> myvar
5
>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mongo shell is an interactive JavaScript shell, so you can use the `delete` operator:

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.3
connecting to: test
> myvar
Wed Feb 20 12:08:35 ReferenceError: myvar is not defined (shell):1
> myvar = {x: 1}
{ "x" : 1 }
> myvar
{ "x" : 1 }
> delete myvar
true
> myvar
Wed Feb 20 12:08:59 ReferenceError: myvar is not defined (shell):1
>
```

Comment: Interesting, I get different output when I do that...I'll edit my question to show.

Comment: I also declared my variable with var -- does that make a difference?

Comment: @jeffstorey The difference is explained here http://www.javascripter.net/faq/deleteavariable.htm

Comment: I get 'Deleting local variable in strict mode'

Answer (score 1):

You can also remove fields in a document stored in a variable.  This sample code shows how to remove the field called "oops" from the rectangle document.

```
> var rectangle = { "length":5, "width":10, "oops":20 }
{ "length":5, "width":10, "oops":20 }

> delete rectangle.oops
true

> rectangle
{ "length":5, "width":10 }
```